# How can i make a stacked multiple density plot with ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I have a dataset with 2 columns. The first one is a factor and it simply says the group name, and the second one are the values. I can make one histogram by filtering one group and using geom_histogram. I could also make several histograms on the same plane by using aes(fill=column1), or even make a individual plot for each group histogram by using facet_wrap.

But how could I get to something like this? (Its a graph from an newspaper on Mexico's elections)
[image: histograms by groups]

Here is some sample code to generate dummy data, I don't have the real data, but it is the aesthetics I am looking for.

```
PRI <- rnorm(10000,mean=20,sd=5)
PAN <- rnorm(10000,mean=100,sd=20)
PRD <- rnorm(10000,mean=80,sd=15)
MORENA <- rnorm(10000,mean=244,sd=50)
PRI <- data.frame(group="PRI",value=PRI)
PAN <- data.frame(group="PAN",value=PAN)
PRD <- data.frame(group="PRD",value=PRD)
MORENA <- data.frame(group="MORENA",value=MORENA)

data <- rbind(PRI,PAN,PRD,MORENA)
ggplot(data=data,aes(x=value,fill=group))+
geom_histogram(bins=1000)
```

Comment: Please share a little bit of sample data so we have something to demonstrate on. Either use `dput()` to share copy/pasteable data or share code to simulate data.

Comment: See the `ggridges` package for the `geom_density_ridges(stat = "binline",...` function.

Comment: @GregorThomas . I don't have the data, but let's imagine a code like the one I added to the question. Is not the numbers I'm looking for right now, is the aesthetics of this graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a good tutorial on how to use `geom_density_ridges` in `ggplot2` from [DataNovia](https://www.datanovia.com/en/blog/elegant-visualization-of-density-distribution-in-r-using-ridgeline/).

Here is a quick example using the `iris` dataset:

```
library(ggridges)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Species)) + 
  geom_density_ridges(fill = "#00AFBB", rel_min_height = 0.01)
```

[image: result]

Comment: This is great! Is there a way to make them translucid and as they overlap when it increases the opacity as in the sample image of the question?