# R: Plotting Multiple Densities on the Same Graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am working with the R programming language.

Recently, I came across this post [How can i make a stacked multiple density plot with ggplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67408356/how-can-i-make-a-stacked-multiple-density-plot-with-ggplot) which showed a very interesting graph:

[image]

**I am trying to learn how to replicate this graph.**

I first simulated the data for this graph:

```
text = c(
"Morena, pvem, pt 307[282-326] Actual 413",
"Morena, PT 263[244-280] Actual 303",
"Morena, pvem 265[243-282] Actual 267",
"PAN, PRI, PRD, MC 193 [167-211] Actual 163",
"PAN,PRI, PRD 180[155-199] Actual 137",
"PAN, PRI 152[131-167]  Actual 126",
"PAN, PRD 112[95-125] Actual 89",
"PRI, PRF 97[83-111] Actual 59"
)


means = c(300,250,200,150,140,130,120,110)

data = data.frame()

for(i in seq_along(text)){
  
  random_numbers = rnorm(100, means[i], 10)
  
  df = data.frame(text = text[i], numbers = random_numbers)
  
  data = rbind(data, df)
}

Titles = c(

"Curules totales por bloques legislativos",
"Curules totales",
"Mayoria absoluta",
"Mayoria calificada"
)
```

I then tried to replicate this graph:

```
library(ggridges)


data$color <- ifelse(data$text %in% levels(data$text)[5:8], "maroon", "blue")

ggplot(data, aes(x = numbers, y = text, fill = color)) +
    geom_density_ridges() +
    scale_fill_identity() +
    labs(x = "Numbers", y = "Text") +
    theme_ridges() +
    ggtitle("Ridge Plot of Text vs Numbers")
```

[image]

However, the aesthetics of my graph looks nothing like the original picture - can someone please show me how I can make something which more closely resembles the original picture?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps `geom_density_ridges(stat = "binline", bins = 200, scale = 0.95, draw_baseline = FALSE,  color = NA)`?

Comment: The text along the left could be done nicely with `ggtext`.

Comment: You should first describe what features that at different matter to you: multi line text in margin, smoothed density versus raw histogram, vertical lines with labels?  Then search. Then say why the search results do not satisfy.

Comment: The original plot has histograms, not density curves. They are also partially transparent.

Comment: `stat = "binline"` will make `geom_density_ridges` output histograms, which in this case should have a high number of bins to match the example.

Comment: I think it is easier to find out a solution for your question in graphics than in ggplot2 syntax.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is my best attempt. [image]

There is still some work to be done:

- the white rectangle that affects the colour of the histograms to the left of 250.
- Correct font
- Correct colours for the plot grid (currently black)

Here is my code (based on what you had already done). The labels can be done in a neater way by collating summary statistics in a rich text format.

```
text = c(
  "<span style='font-size:9pt; color:#999999'>MORENA, PVEM, PT</span><br>**307**<span style='font-size:9pt; color:#999999'> [282-326]<br>Actual:</span><span style='font-size:9pt; color:black'>**413**</span>",
  "<span style='font-size:9pt; color:#999999'>MORENA, PT<br></span>**263**<span style='font-size:9pt; color:#999999'> [244-280]<br>Actual:</span><span style='font-size:9pt; color:black'>**303**</span>",
  "<span style='font-size:9pt; color:#999999'>MORENA, PVEM <br></span>**265**<span style='font-size:9pt; color:#999999'> [243-282]<br>Actual:</span><span style='font-size:9pt; color:black'>**267**</span>",
  "<span style='font-size:9pt; color:#999999'>PAN, PRI, PRD, MC <br></span>**193**<span style='font-size:9pt; color:#999999'> [167-211]<br>Actual:</span><span style='font-size:9pt; color:black'>**163**</span>",
  "<span style='font-size:9pt; color:#999999'>PAN,PRI, PRD <br></span>**180**<span style='font-size:9pt; color:#999999'> [155-199]<br>Actual:</span><span style='font-size:9pt; color:black'>**137**</span>",
  "<span style='font-size:9pt; color:#999999'>PAN, PRI<br></span>**152**<span style='font-size:9pt; color:#999999'> [131-167]<br>Actual:</span><span style='font-size:9pt; color:black'>**126**</span>",
  "<span style='font-size:9pt; color:#999999'>PAN, PRD<br></span>**112**<span style='font-size:9pt; color:#999999'> [95-125]<br>Actual:</span><span style='font-size:9pt; color:black'>**89**</span>",
  "<span style='font-size:9pt; color:#999999'>PRI, PRF<br></span>**97**<span style='font-size:9pt; color:#999999'> [83-111]<br>Actual:</span><span style='font-size:9pt; color:black'>**59**</span>"
)


means = c(310,270,260,190,170,150,110,100)

data = data.frame()

for(i in seq_along(text)){
  
  random_numbers = rnorm(1500, means[i], 10+rpois(1,lambda = 4))
  
  df = data.frame(text = text[i], numbers = random_numbers)
  
  data = rbind(data, df)
}

Titles = c(
  "Curules totales por bloques legislativos",
  "Curules totales",
  "**Mayoría<br>absoluta**",
  "**Mayoría<br>calificada**"
)

library(ggridges)
library(ggtext)


data$color <- ifelse(data$text %in% text[1:3], "#792C32", "#537DAB")

x_labels = c(as.character(seq(100,200,50)),"<b>250</b>","300","350")

test = ggplot(data, aes(x = numbers, y = fct_reorder(text,numbers,mean), fill = color)) +
  geom_density_ridges(stat = "binline",
                      bins = 150,
                      #scale = 0.95,
                      draw_baseline = FALSE,
                      color = NA,alpha = 0.8) +
  # geom_rect(aes(xmin = 50, xmax = 250, ymin = 1, ymax = 9),col = NA,fill = "white",alpha = 0.006)+
  geom_segment(aes(x = 250, y = 1, xend = 250, yend = 9), linewidth = 0.3,col="black")+
  geom_segment(aes(x = 326, y = 1, xend = 326, yend = 9), linewidth = 0.3,col="black")+
  geom_richtext(data = data.frame(text = Titles[4],
                                  y = 9.5),inherit.aes = F,
                aes(x = 326, y = y, label = text),
                fill=NA,label.color = NA,hjust = 0.5,vjust=1,size=2.5)+
  scale_fill_identity() +
  geom_richtext(data = data.frame(text = Titles[3],
                                  y = 9.5),inherit.aes = F,
                aes(x = 250, y = y, label = text),
                fill=NA,label.color = NA,hjust = 0.5,vjust=1,size=2.5)+
  geom_richtext(data = data.frame(text,y = seq(8.5,1.5,-1)),inherit.aes = F,
            aes(x = 50, y = y, label = text),
            fill=NA,label.color = NA,hjust = 1)+
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,360),
                     breaks = seq(100,350,50),
                     labels = x_labels)+
  scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0.0, 0))+
  labs(title = Titles[1],
       x = Titles[2],
       y = "") +
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(panel.grid.major.y = element_line(linewidth = 0.3,colour = "black"),
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_markdown())
```

Answer (score 1):

As I commented, maybe it is easier to do it in graphics than in ggplot2. That is an (yet incomplete) example using graphics.

[image]

The code:

```
# Create data -------------------------------------------------------------

mainData <- data.frame(name = c("MORENA, PVEM, PT", "MORENA, PT", "MORENA, PVEM",
                                "PAN, PRI, PRD, MC", "PAN, PRI, PRD", "PAN, PRI",
                                "PAN, PRD", "PRI, PRD"),
                       actual = c(314, 303, 267, 163, 137, 126, 89, 59),
                       cols = rep(c("red4", "dodgerblue4"), c(3, 5)))

library(truncnorm)

set.seed(666)

rndData <- cbind(means = c(307, 263, 265, 193, 180, 152, 112, 97),
                 min = c(282, 244, 245, 167, 155, 131, 95, 83), 
                 max = c(326, 280, 282, 211, 199, 167, 125, 111)) |> 
  
  apply(2, rev) |> 
  
  apply(1, \(x) rnorm(n = 1.5e4, mean = x[1], sd = 10))


# Define some parameters --------------------------------------------------


xlim <- c(-30, 380)
ylim <- c(0, 200)

# Breaks for histograms
hBreaks <- seq(xlim[1], xlim[2], .5)

# Limits of Mayoría absoluta y calificada
limits <- c(250, 330)


# The plot ----------------------------------------------------------------


# png(filename = "ex1.png", width = 1730, height = 1550, res = 210)

# Set some graphic parameters
par(xaxs = "i", yaxs = "i", mar = c(3, 0, 4.5, 0), family = "Corbel")

# Starting with an empty canvas
plot(1, 1, type = "n", axes = FALSE, xlab = NA, ylab = NA, 
     xlim = xlim, ylim = c(0, diff(ylim)*ncol(rndData) + 200))

# Defining positions for grid
vAxis <- seq(100, 350, 50)
abline(v = vAxis, col = "gray80")

# X axis labels
axis(side = 1, at = vAxis, lwd = 0, line = -1, tick = FALSE)

# Loop along types
for(i in seq(ncol(rndData))){
  
  # Subset data
  tempVals <- hist(x = rndData[,i], breaks = hBreaks, plot = FALSE) |> 
    
    with(data.frame(mids = mids, counts = counts)) %>% 
    
    filter(counts > 0) |> 
    
    as.matrix() 
  
  # Loop along very frequency bar
  for(j in seq(nrow(tempVals))){
    lines(x = rep(tempVals[j, 1], 2), 
          y = c(ylim[2]*(i - 1), tempVals[j, 2] + ylim[2]*(i - 1)),
          col = adjustcolor(mainData$cols[ncol(rndData) - i + 1], 0.65),
          lwd = 1.35)
  }
}

# Add box for Mayoría absoluta
polygon(x = rep(c(xlim[1], limits[1]), each = 2), border = NA, 
        y = par()$usr[c(3, 4, 4, 3)], col = adjustcolor("white", 0.5))

# Add box for Mayoría calificada
polygon(x = rep(c(limits[2], xlim[2]), each = 2), border = NA, 
        y = par()$usr[c(3, 4, 4, 3)], col = adjustcolor("white", 0.5))

# Add name of types
text(x = rep(50, ncol(rndData)), 
     y = ylim[2]*seq(ncol(rndData)) - 40,
     labels = rev(mainData$name), pos = 2)


# Add lines for Mayoría absoluta, calificada and bottom of subplots
abline(v = limits, h = ylim[2]*(seq(ncol(rndData)) - 1), col = "gray40")

# Add top labels for Mayoría absoluta y calificada
axis(side = 3, at = limits, lwd = 0, line = -1,
     labels = paste0("Mayoría\n", c("absoluta", "calificada")))

# Add text on top and bottom# Add box for Mayoría absoluta
mtext(text = "Curules totales", side = 1, line = 1.5)
mtext(text = "Curules totales por bloques legislativos", 
      side = 3, line = 3, adj = 0.01, font = 2, cex = 1.2, col = "gray20")

# dev.off()
```

For setting the typo (Corbel), use the steps on [Changing Fonts for Graphs in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27689222/changing-fonts-for-graphs-in-r)

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! Do you have the code that you used for this?

Comment: @JonSpring Yes, I am sorry. When I finished the code I had to leave my desk and I did considered not to put as it was because it was very untidy.